# How do I fix this build error in the MySQL Workbench VS Project?

Tags: visual-studio, mysql-workbench

I downloaded the MySQL Workbench project from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench.

I opened the .sln file in VS 2015, clicked on Build Project and got a boatload of errors, many of which are like this:

```
stdafx.h(63): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/locale/encoding_utf.hpp': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench needs quite a big number of 3rd party libraries. For reasons we cannot discuss here you have to collect all of them yourself, to be able to build the project. In order to help with that we created [a blog posting](https://mysqlworkbench.org/2015/06/compiling-wb-on-windows/) which describes this process in detail, including download links for each of the dependencies.